# Как изменить состояние компонента извне?

Tags: reactjs

Компонент Header отображает меню, а компонент Main отвечает за отображение информации соответствующей определённому пункту меню. При нажатий на элемент компонента Header должно отображаться соответствующая информация в Main (то есть событие из Header должны изменять состояние компонента Main). Каким образом это организовать? Если setState() можно вызвать только из самого класса любой другой метод тоже. Статические методы могут вызывать только статические методы. Поэтому вопрос такой как при срабатываний событии в одном компоненте изменить состояние другого?

Comment: Можно передать метод, в котором будет меняться состояние, в компонент, посредством `props` и вызывать этот метод из дочернего компонента. Самое простое решение на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае будет удобно использовать Redux. Таким образом все состояние приложения у вас будет храниться в одном месте, и вы будете иметь к нему доступ из любого компонента. Вот документация: https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

С другой стороны, если не хотите подключать сторонние библиотеки, есть несколько способов реализации подобного функционала.

1.Вынести состояние в родительский компонент

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    foo: 'bar'
  }

  changeFoo = (payload) => {
    this.setState({foo: payload})
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <Fragment>
        <Header handleChange={this.changeFoo}/>
        <Main foo={this.state.foo} />
       </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

2.Использовать контекст (подробнее тут https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)